# One time execution of a variable incrementation

Tags: arduino-uno, c

As part of a larger script intended for a very simple arduino "synthesizer" I am trying to increment the amount of cycles a melody will be played once a key is pressed (the key in turn passes a value to the variable selectMel). The problem I encounter is that the moment I call my function in the main void loop() function, I cannot control the incrementation of the variable ncycles, which is intended to be only increased once per key press. I tried to solve this by creating a global switchVar variable as an "on/off" switch but that did not do much to solve the issue at hand.

Any tips or help will be greatly appreciated!

PS: I have of course googled and tried the solutions posted on similar stackExchange posts but to no avail, sadly.

```
      void playMan (int ncycles, int mSpeed) {

        switch (selectMel) {
        case 1:
          if (ncycles > 0) {
            tone(12, NOTE_B7, mSpeed);
            delay(100);
            tone(12, NOTE_B5, mSpeed);
            delay(100);
            tone(12, NOTE_B3, mSpeed);
            delay(100);
            tone(12, NOTE_B1, mSpeed);
            delay(100);
            ncycles--;
            break;
          case 2:
            if (millis() % 100 == 0) {
              if (switchVar == 1) {
                ncycles += 5;
                switchVar = 0;
              }
              Serial << ncycles << endl;
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.gammon.com.au/switches.

Basically you need to detect the transition between the switch not being pressed before, and **now** being pressed. This transition will occur once per press (possibly after you add debouncing). If you just test for the switch pressed naturally you will get multiple increments.

---

> Assuming I add debouncing, how would it help in incrementing the value of ncycles only once ?

To clarify, you increment once on a transition, note when you did this (eg, by calling `millis()` ) and then ignore any further transitions for, say 10 ms.

Comment: Assuming I add debouncing, how would it help in incrementing the value of ncycles only once ? From what I understand debouncing is only helpful as a means of toggling from one state to another without the "noise" of outside factors, or is there something I am missing entirely?

Comment: I have just found a solution to my own question, albeit not without your kind help Mr. Gammon, thank you!